# Javascript Detect End Video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video

I'm trying to play a random video with javascript when an html page loads.
Basically i create an array of videos which are supported by each browser.
But i have to run a function when the videos end. I try to use iframe tag to tell the browser the video is ended because all videos i have are call using the iframe tag. However it doesn't work. The function i'm talking about is the last line of code.
Any help please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var videosFirefox = ['la_redoute_h264.ogv','la_redoute_h264.ogv'];
var videosSafari = ['la_redoute_h264.mp4','la_redoute_h264.mp4'];
var videosGoogleChrome = ['la_redoute_h264.mp4','la_redoute_h264.mp4'];

var indexFirefox=Math.floor(Math.random() * videosFirefox.length);
var htmlFirefox='<div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe width="500" height="290" src="http://wificontent.go4digital.pt/laredoute/20140204/' + videosFirefox[indexFirefox] + '" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';

var indexSafari=Math.floor(Math.random() * videosSafari.length);
var htmlSafari='<div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe width="500" height="290" src="http://wificontent.go4digital.pt/laredoute/20140204/' + videosSafari[indexSafari] + '" controls="controls" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';

var indexGoogleChrome=Math.floor(Math.random() * videosGoogleChrome.length);
var htmlGoogleChrome='<div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe class="ivideo" width="500" height="290" src="http://wificontent.go4digital.pt/laredoute/20140204/' + videosGoogleChrome[indexGoogleChrome] + '" controls="controls" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';


var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
var is_Firefox = /firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (isChrome) document.write(htmlGoogleChrome);
if (isSafari) document.write(htmlSafari);
if (is_Firefox) document.write(htmlFirefox);

var ivideo = document.getElementsByClassName('ivideo');
ivideo.addEventListener('ended', function(){ 
    document.login.submit();
},false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to leverage the HTML5 `<video>` tag for playback. Is there a compelling reason that you are using `<iframe>` instead of `<video>`? According to [this video events demo page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html), the "ended" event does indeed fire at the end of video playback. I can't find any evidence that the `<iframe>` tag supports an "ended" event.

Comment: I tried video tag, but i forget to activate the controls and the autoplay so the video didn't start. Now it's done. And i gave a class to all my video and i call that class in the function. Btw thanks for the answer ;)